# How to create a parallel prefetch for a foreach

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

Given the numerous new ways of performing asynchronous operations in C#, TPL, Parallel Extensions, Async CTP, Reactive Extensions I was wonder what the simplest way to parallelize the fetching and processing portions of the following would be:

```
foreach(string url in urls)
{
   var file = FetchFile(url);
   ProcessFile(file);
}
```

The proviso is that whilst files can be fetched at anytime `ProcessFile` can only handle one file at a time and should be called sequentially.

In short what is the simplest way to get `FetchFile` and `ProcessFile` to behave in a pipelined way i.e. happen concurrently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's RX way. This extension will transform a steam of uri's into a stream of streams:

```
    public static IObservable<Stream> RequestToStream(this IObservable<string> source, 
    TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        return
            from wc in source.Select(WebRequest.Create)
            from s in Observable
                .FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(wc.BeginGetResponse,
                    wc.EndGetResponse)()
                .Timeout(timeout, Observable.Empty<WebResponse>())
                .Catch(Observable.Empty<WebResponse>())
            select s.GetResponseStream();
    }
```

Usage:

```
new [] { "myuri.net\file1.dat", "myuri.net\file2.dat" }
   .ToObservable()
   .RequestToStream(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
   .Do(stream = > ProcessStream(stream))
   .Subscribe();
```

Edit: oops, haven't noticed the file write serialization requirement. This part can be done by employing .Concat which is essentially an RX queue (another one is .Zip)

Let's have a .StreamToFile extension:

```
    public static IObservable<Unit> StreamToFile(this Tuple<Stream, string> source)
    {
        return Observable.Defer(() =>
            source.Item1.AsyncRead().WriteTo(File.Create(source.Item2)));
    }
```

now you can have web requests parallel but serialize file writing that comes from them:

```
        new[] { "myuri.net\file1.dat", "myuri.net\file2.dat" }
            .ToObservable()
            .RequestToStream(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            .Select((stream, i) => Tuple.Create(stream, i.ToString() + ".dat"))
            .Select(x => x.StreamToFile())
            .Concat()
            .Subscribe();
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that ProcessStream is only called on one thread at a time

Answer (score 1):

Given the constraint on `ProcessFile` I would say you should fetch the data asynchronously using TPL and then enqueue a token which references the preloaded data. You can then have a background thread that pulls items off the queue and hands them to the ProcessFile one by one. This is a [producer/consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) pattern.

For the queue you can take a look at [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) which can provide a threadsafe queue which also has the nice effect of being able to throttle the workload.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know all the fancy mechanisms, I'd probably do it in the old fashion way, although I doubt it would classify as "simple":

```
var q = new Queue<MyFile>();
var ev = new ManualResetEvent(false);

new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
{
    while ( true )
    {
        ev.WaitOne();
        MyFile item;
        lock (q)
        {
            item = q.Dequeue();
            if ( q.Count == 0 )
                ev.Reset();
        }
        if ( item == null )
            break;
        ProcessFile(item);
    }
}).Start();
foreach(string url in urls)
{
    var file = FetchFile(url);
    lock (q)
    {
        q.Enqueue(file);
        ev.Set();
    }
}
lock (q)
{
    q.Enqueue(null);
    ev.Set();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous does not actually denote parallel. It simply means that your will not block waiting for another operation. But you you take advantage of async I/O to not block threads as you download the URLs, i.e. you don't need as many threads as urls to download them in parallel if you do this:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var syncLock = new object();
TaskEx.WhenAll(urls.Select(url => {
  client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url).ContinueWith((t) => {
    lock(syncLock) {
      ProcessFile(t.Result);
    }
  });
}));
```

Basically we create a async download task per url and then as any task completes, we invoke a continuation that uses a plain object as out synclock for making sure `ProcessFile` happens sequentially. `WhenAll` won't return until the last `ProcessFile` continuation is done.

You could avoid the explicit lock with RX's `ReplaySubject` (but of course it will lock internally):

```
var pipeline = new ReplaySubject<byte[]>();
var files = pipeline.ToEnumerable();
var client = new WebClient();
TaskEx.WhenAll(urls
        .Select(download => client.DownloadDataTaskAsync((string) download)
            .ContinueWith(t => pipeline.OnNext(t.Result))
        )
    ).ContinueWith(task => pipeline.OnCompleted(task));
foreach(var file in files) {
    ProcessFile(file);
}
```

Here we use a `ReplaySubject` as our pipeline of file downloads. Each download finishes asynchronously and publishes its results into the pipeline which the `foreach` blocks on (i.e. happens sequentially). When all tasks complete, we complete the observable, which exits the `foreach`.